# How to configure SymbolSource Server Basic

Tags: nuget, nuget-server, symbol-server

I have [SymbolSource Server Basic](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2012-03-13/Releasing_the_community_edition_of_SymbolSource) installed and running, following the instructions in [Xavier Decosters blog entry](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step).

I have set up Visual Studio as [recommended by SymbolSource](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio)

The problem is that the Symbol Server returns 404's for all the url's that Visual Studio asks for.

Visual Studio accesses the following urls when trying to load the pdb:

- http.../WinDbg/pdb/MightyLittleGeodesy.pdb/82A03D09EC754F5893C3806CDA329EC92/MightyLittleGeodesy.pdb
- http.../WinDbg/pdb/MightyLittleGeodesy.pdb/82A03D09EC754F5893C3806CDA329EC92/MightyLittleGeodesy.pd_
- http.../WinDbg/pdb/MightyLittleGeodesy.pdb/82A03D09EC754F5893C3806CDA329EC92/file.ptr

  [image: 404 errors from Fiddler]

The SymbolServer website has the following:

- \...\Data\MightyLittleGeodesy\1.0.0.0\Binaries\MightyLittleGeodesy\82A03D09EC754F5893C3806CDA329EC92\MightyLittleGeodesy.pdb

  [image: Symbol Server Data Directory]

I have tried a large number of url variations in a browser, and I cannot get the Symbol server to return anything other than a 404 for any of them.

Does anyone know what to do here?

Thanks - Cedd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any errors refer http://localhost/%your_app%/elmah.axd

If you faced with 404.* errors then you should check the following conditions:

1. Add write permissions onto 'Data' directory of application for IIS_IUSRS group
2. Create separate AppPool for application and enable 32bit option
3. Add MIME types for both .pdb (application/octet-stream) and .cs (text/plain) file types
4. Edit web.config and add the following lines:

   ```
   <location path="Data">
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <clear />
       <add name="Deny" verb="*" path="*.config" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
       <add name="Allow" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     </handlers>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
           <clear />
        <add fileExtension=".cs" allowed="true" />
         </fileExtensions>
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

   ```
   <location path="WinDbg/pdbsrc">
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <clear />
       <add name="Deny" verb="*" path="*.config" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
       <add name="Allow" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     </handlers>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
           <clear />
        <add fileExtension=".cs" allowed="true" />
         </fileExtensions>
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

My version of SymbolSource is 1.3.3

Comment: Thanks for that. I've basically moved away from Symbol Server now, it seems to have died. I have been recommended dotPeek as a more convenient solution.